# Angular Why is the length of this HTTP requests response Array undefined?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, http

I'm trying to get data which contains information about lobbies that clients can join. I get this data from an springboot API. For the data to be displayed in my angular frontend I add the results to a Set that is a property of a component. But after getting this data from the API and mapping it into a object Array i can't iterate through the results. All because the length of the array is said the be undefined.

I am using the newest version of Angular (Currently 7) and already tried to map the JSON response differently with the map method. Instead of using the subscribe function. Also directly assigning the response to an other array gives this error: LobbyComponent.html:10 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object **'[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

**The Component**

```
export class LobbyComponent implements OnInit {

  lobbies: Set<Lobby>;
  constructor(private lobbyService: LobbyService) { }

  getLobbies(): void {
    this.lobbyService.getLobbies().subscribe(response => {

      console.log(response);


      // This solutions give this error: ERROR TypeError: response.forEach is not a function
      // response.forEach(element => console.log(element.id)) 

      //Todo: fix response.length is undifenided
      console.log(response.length)
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        this.lobbies.add(response[i])
      }
    })
      ;
  }
```

**The Service**

```
getLobbies(): Observable<Lobby[]> {
    return this.http.get<Lobby[]>(this.apiURL+"/lobbies").pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`Got lobbies`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Lobby[]>('getLobbies', []))
    );
  }
```

**Lobby Class**

```
export class Lobby{
    id: string;
    slots: User[]
}
```

**JSON Result from the API**

```
"lobbies": [
        {
            "users": null,
            "id": "Another Lobby!"
        },
        {
            "users": null,
            "id": "This is a Lobby!"
        }
    ]
```

I expected the code to loop through the results and add them to the set in the component. But since the length is undefined it won't iterate through the response elements.
And trying to use an forEach instead of a for loop gives this error: **ERROR TypeError: response.forEach is not a function**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your API doesn't return an array, but an object containing an array. So you should

```
getLobbies(): Observable<Lobby[]> {
// find a neat name for T, it'll be an object containing a property `lobbies` of type Lobby[]
    return this.http.get<T>(this.apiURL+"/lobbies").pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`Got lobbies`)),
      catchError(/* error handling logic here */),
      map(({ lobbies }) => lobbies),
    );
  }
```